# Handling Apple Push Notification when app is inactive

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I wonder how lookout www.lookout.com implement there scream functionality on ios. Since when the app is in inactive mode(The user pressed home button) , there's no way to handle the notification (since didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called ). So how did they make the phone scream when receiving notification unless customizing the alert sound but I don't think that is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use custom sound while sending out notifications .

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method :

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if (launchOptions != nil) {
       apnsDict=[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    //handle more here
    }
}
```

If you have received any notification while your app was inactive, you will get this condition true in this method whenever you will open your application.

Comment: But I want to handle the notification by sounding alarm tone until the user open the app,not after he open the application

Comment: While registering for APNS you have to set the default settings in pay load such as:{
 "aps":
 {
 "alert": "Hello, world!",
 "sound": "default"
 }
}
IOS will automatically handle using these settings to show a notification with message and tone if you app is not running.

Comment: have you tried their Lookout app? the sound increase the system volume gradually until you open the app to stop the sound . Actually you can lower the volume but it will increase much faster . So I don't think that's a custom sound. Any ideas?